# How can I emulate a static initialization method that returns void instead of using a static constructor?

Tags: c#

I wanted to eliminate using a static constructor because I was getting the CA1810 warning that advised against it. So I created a static initialization method that returns a string because it can't return a void. But I don't have any use for the string and warning CA1823 then appears telling me to use the returned string or remove it. Is there any way to avoid both of these warnings? This is my code:

```
internal abstract class Loggers
{
       protected static string initializer = initalizeLogger();

        protected static string initalizeLogger()
        {
            ReloadConfig();
            return ""; //couldn't be void
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you call *Loggers.ReloadConfig()* explicitly at program start, for example?

Comment: Which logger are you using?  NLog (for example) allows things like 'static readonly ILogger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();'

Comment: @Rich Also you can suppress warning message CA1810. Do you consider to suppress it? According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1810?view=vs-2019#when-to-suppress-warnings) it is safe to suppress this warning.